# Is it possible to change the correlation in the middle of the workflow?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, correlation

I have put an InitializeCorrelation activity in the beginning of the workflow and then I want to correlate on a different keys, so I've put another InitializeCorrelation activity with a different keys but I am getting this error:

> The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance key 'a765c209-5adc-4f03-9dd2-1af5e33aab3b' was not associated to an instance. This can occur because the instance or key has been cleaned up, or because the key is invalid. The key may be invalid if the message it was generated from was sent at the wrong time or contained incorrect correlation data.

So, is it possible to change the correlation after the workflow started or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question explicitly, yes, you can change the data the correlation based on. You can do it in not only within a sequence but you can use different correlation data within each branch of a Parallel activity. Correlation can be initialized using an InitializeCorrelation or a SendReply activity as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358755(v=vs.100).aspx.

As the Workflow Designer is not the strongest part of Visual Studio (XPath queries are never checked, sometimes even build errors are not reflected on activities, etc.), usually it is not always obvious what the problem is. So, I suggest the followings:

- initialize a CorrelationHandle only once with the correlation type *Query correlation* for a specicific correlation data
- initialize a new CorrelationHandle instance for a different correlation data
- once a CorrelationHandle is initialized, it can be used later for multiple times for different Receive activities (Receive.CorrelatesOn, Receive.CorrelatesWith)
- if correlation does not work it can be because of wrong XPath queries. These are not refreshed automatically if the OperationName or parameters' name are changed. It is advisable to regenerate them after renaming
- it can be a good idea to turn off workflow persistance and NLB while you are testing - to let yourself concentrate on correlation-related problems

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into Instances table in database where you store persisted instaces. One of the entries would probably have the suspended state, there is also a column with some error description. What have caused this error ? have you done some changes in workflow and deployed it ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply..

Actually i can't find the error column. I am using AppFabric to persist the workflow. I didn't make any change in the workflow. I put a receive activity and the error happens when i call this receive. I think it's something related to the correlation process.